# Pypi & PyPi Test Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, distutils, pypi

I am trying to release software through pypi, and while pip can search for the library, it is unable to download the library.

I suspect it is an issue with the setup.py file,

```
doclines = __doc__.split("\n")
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='Directory_Caching',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='1.0.6',
    description = doclines[0],
    long_description = "\n".join(doclines[2:]),
    author='Benjamin Schollnick',
    author_email='benjamin@schollnick.net',
    license="MIT",
    maintainer='Benjamin Schollnick',
    maintainer_email='benjamin@schollnick.net',
    platforms=["Any"],
    url='https://github.com/bschollnick/Directory_Caching',
    download_url = 'https://github.com/bschollnick/Directory_Caching/tarball/1.05',
    #install_requires=required,
    #requires=required,
    keywords = ['caching', 'files', 'directories', 'scandir', 'naturalsort'],
    classifiers=filter(None, classifiers.split("\n")),
)
```

Pypitest is accepting the file fine, via register, and the sdist upload is working fine.

-- Register

```
nerv:Directory_caching Benjamin$ python setup.py register -r pypitest
running register
running egg_info
deleting Directory_Caching.egg-info/requires.txt
writing Directory_Caching.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Directory_Caching.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Directory_Caching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering Directory_Caching to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
nerv:Directory_caching Benjamin$ python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest
running sdist
running egg_info
writing Directory_Caching.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Directory_Caching.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Directory_Caching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt

running check
creating Directory_Caching-1.0.503
creating Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching
creating Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching.egg-info
making hard links in Directory_Caching-1.0.503...
hard linking setup.cfg -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503
hard linking setup.py -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503
hard linking Directory_Caching/__init__.py -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching
hard linking Directory_Caching/directory_caching.py -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching.egg-info
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching.egg-info
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching.egg-info
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/top_level.txt -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503/Directory_Caching.egg-info
copying setup.cfg -> Directory_Caching-1.0.503
Writing Directory_Caching-1.0.503/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'Directory_Caching-1.0.503' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting dist/Directory_Caching-1.0.503.tar.gz to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
nerv:Directory_caching Benjamin$ python setup.py register -r pypitest
running register
running egg_info
writing Directory_Caching.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Directory_Caching.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Directory_Caching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering Directory_Caching to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

upload

```
nerv:Directory_caching Benjamin$ python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest
running sdist
running egg_info
writing Directory_Caching.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Directory_Caching.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Directory_Caching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt

running check
creating Directory_Caching-1.0.504
creating Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching
creating Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching.egg-info
making hard links in Directory_Caching-1.0.504...
hard linking setup.cfg -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504
hard linking setup.py -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504
hard linking Directory_Caching/__init__.py -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching
hard linking Directory_Caching/directory_caching.py -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching.egg-info
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching.egg-info
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching.egg-info
hard linking Directory_Caching.egg-info/top_level.txt -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504/Directory_Caching.egg-info
copying setup.cfg -> Directory_Caching-1.0.504
Writing Directory_Caching-1.0.504/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'Directory_Caching-1.0.504' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting dist/Directory_Caching-1.0.504.tar.gz to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

If I run a verbose run on pip, the following errors appear to be the problem?

```
Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching/1.0.504 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching); unknown archive format: .504
Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching/1.0.503 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching); unknown archive format: .503
Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching/1.0.502 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching); unknown archive format: .502
Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching/1.0.501 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching); unknown archive format: .501
Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching/1.0.51 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching); unknown archive format: .51
Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching/1.0.5 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/Directory_Caching); unknown archive format: .5
```

I have setup tags at Github (https://github.com/bschollnick/Directory_Caching), and using the links in pypi or pypi test appear to work fine.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, this the basic setup i use though with no problem.

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
  name = 'name',
  packages = ['package'],
  version = '1.0.0',
  author = 'your name',
  author_email = 'some_email@gmail.com',
  url = 'github', 
  download_url = 'git download link', 
  keywords = ['keywords'],
  description = 'short description', 
  long_description = read('README.txt'),
  classifiers = [],
)
```